# Passing multiple parameters to a controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a situation where I need to pass two parameters to an action. I've been passing parameters to actions using the code below but I don't see how I pass multiple parameters.  How do I do this?

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Add Visit", "Create", "Visit", new { id = Model.Id }, null)
```

BTW - ASP.NET MVC 4 RC

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should separate the parameters with comma, like this:

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Add Visit", "Create", "Visit", 
                  new { id = Model.Id, secondParameter = Model.yourValue }, null)
```

Check the MSDN documentation for the [ActionLink](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink.aspx) method.

Hope it helps!

Comment: @user1469655 could you please mark this(or any other) response as the answer to your question.... at least if you were able to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I add from CodePlex called [T4MVC](http://t4mvc.codeplex.com/). 
This turns all your strings into a method call by using a combination of T4 templates and partial classes.
It will allow you to turn your ActionLink methods into a syntax checked method call.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Add Visit", "Create", "Visit", new { id = Model.Id }, null)
```

would be turned into

```
@Html.ActionLink("Add Visit", MVC.Visit.Create(Model.Id))
```

and

```
@Html.ActionLink("Add Visit", "Create", "Visit", new { id = Model.Id, Param2 = "Param2", Param3= "Param3Value" }, null)
@Html.ActionLink("Add Visit", MVC.Visit.Create(Model.Id, "Param2", "Param3Value"))
```

Its a life saver when you turn on compiled views.